# Why is grub still in my bios?

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu before when I was using Windows 8.1. Now I have installed windows 10 after a removing ubuntu. I did a clean install of windows but still have grub in my bios. When i boot into it it just opens grub like a terminal.What should I do to remove the grub from my boot loader?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the Windows 10 installation disc in the disc drive, and power cycle your PC after setting it to boot from CD Drive in BIOS.(Or LiveUSB)
2. Press any key when you are prompted & select [language, time, currency, keyboard etc.] & click *Next*. Select *Repair Your Computer* option in the dialog window.
3. In the *System Recovery Options* window Click the 1<sup>st</sup> Option *Startup Repair* and let it do what it wants to do, but in my case it didn’t solve the problem so I went to the next step.
4. In the *System Recovery Options* dialog box, go to the last option i.e. *Command Prompt*.
5. Once in the command prompt (`X:\Sources>`), type exactly the following commands in the same sequence

   ```
   bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
   C:
   CD Boot
   Attrib bcd –s –h –r
   ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
   bootrec /RebuildBcd
   ```

   then it said

   ```
   Scanning all disks for windows installations.
   Please wait, since this may take a while…
   Successfully scanned windows installations: 1
   [1] C:\windows
   Add installations to boot list? Yes(y)/No(N)/All(A) :
   ```

   I pressed `Y` as there was only one instance of windows installation. Then it said The operation completed successfully.
6. Next enter the following command `bootrec /fixmbr`. It said The operation completed successfully.
7. Next enter the following command `bootrec /FixBoot`. Again It said The operation completed successfully.
8. Set the BIOS again to boot from the HDD and reboot.

GRUB was gone & finally the windows 10 was booting again

reference [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-you-remove-ubuntu-and-grub/42d3f550-bf5f-459d-94ed-4cbadd7c933c?auth=1)